# Creating a X input matrix and y output vector via Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

if I have a dataset which has 5 columns and 10 rows(thus 10 observations), where I want X to be a 10 by 4 input matrix representing the first four columns and y to be a 10 by 1 output matrix representing the last column in my dataset, how would I code that on python?
 I want my X matrix to incorporate the columns: cty_pop2000,    countyfipscode,county_name and statename. While I want my y output vector to be the gini column. How would I code this on Python? Apologies if this question is trivial, I'm new to Python. 
I've tried [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html) but they use simple arrays for their X input and y output. Therefore, I have no idea how to code my X matrix and y vector

I tried coding it using the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
X  =  df.iloc[[0:3]]    
y  =  df['gini']
```

The dataset is a csv file that has the following:

```
cty_pop2000 countyfipscode  county_name statename   gini
43671   1001    Autauga Alabama 0.381
43671   1001    Autauga Alabama 0.381
43671   1001    Autauga Alabama 0.381
43671   1001    Autauga Alabama 0.381
43671   1001    Autauga Alabama 0.381
43671   1001    Autauga Alabama 0.381
43671   1001    Autauga Alabama 0.381
43671   1001    Autauga Alabama 0.381
43671   1001    Autauga Alabama 0.381
```

Comment: Use the word 'column' instead of 'feature'. Your data is not that big. Just post it so that people can see. How is it separated? By commas or by white spaces, etc. All can be answered by showing your small set of data.

Comment: the actual dataset has 34 features and 28,243 rows(its a csv file labeled raw_data_for_project2.csv and I don't know how to upload it on this site). I'm trying to construct a neural network in which my X matrix is  28,243 by 33 and my y vector is  28,243 by 1. The y vector is the last column on my csv file

Comment: I've tried 

import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('raw_data_for_project2.csv')
 
X  =  df.iloc[0:32]    
y  =  df['absoluteupwardmobility']   # the name of the last feature

Comment: The error message I get is "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (84735,) (3,)"

Comment: You'll need to give an example of your input data file (just the first few lines), give the relevant code that causes the crash (probably the 2, 3 lines from your comment), and the full traceback of the crash. Please try and [edit] it all into your question.

Comment: Note that your question is rather generic, while your comments suggest an actual error. I'm not sure if you want to know the former (in which the question might be closed as being too broad, without seeing proper example data, precise expected output and an attempt at solving it yourself); or whether you just want to get the ValueError fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the last column to a vector and drop it from the original dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
y  =  df[['gini']] 
X  =  df.drop(['gini'])
```

Or you can simply slice out the 'gini' column without dropping

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
y  =  df[['gini']] 
X  =  df[df.columns.difference(['gini'])]
```

You can also slice out the columns using their column indices:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
y  =  df[[-1]] 
X  =  df[df.columns[0:-1]]
```

all of these methods would give you for y

```
>> y
    gini
0  0.381
1  0.381
2  0.381
3  0.381
4  0.381
5  0.381
6  0.381
7  0.381
8  0.381
```

and for X

```
>> X 
   cty_pop2000  countyfipscode county_name statename
0        43671            1001     Autauga   Alabama
1        43671            1001     Autauga   Alabama
2        43671            1001     Autauga   Alabama
3        43671            1001     Autauga   Alabama
4        43671            1001     Autauga   Alabama
5        43671            1001     Autauga   Alabama
6        43671            1001     Autauga   Alabama
7        43671            1001     Autauga   Alabama
8        43671            1001     Autauga   Alabama
```